# Getting Input in the Models class method Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
Public void getmsg(string txt) 
{ 
    //...some code.... 
}
```

This is a method in a class named `sample.cs` in Models.

I want to take data from `HTML` input tag into `string txt` in that method

How will I do it in Asp.Net MVC?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is take a look at [model binding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)... Model binding automates the process of retrieve each value and convert them to .NET types and it is what you need to understand to apply in your code.

If you are not using asp .net core, you can take a look at [this one.](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-model-binding/)